# уникальный идентификатор в итерации

Tags: php, mysql, парсер, итераторы

Добрый день.
Подскажите начинающему шаману как реализовать следующее.

Я делаю парсинг определенный контент и делю его на 4 части (id, theme, description, time).
 С тремя последними параметрами понятно и просто.
Но, на данный момент у меня запись в базу данных организована плохо.
Дословно:

```
<?php
    $i=$i+1;
    echo $el->title . PHP_EOL;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $el->description . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    echo "<br> <hr>";
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO cont SET typeid='".$i."', theme='".$el->title . ' ' . $el->description."', times=NOW()");
?>
```

В общем получается при каждом использовании данного кода я, во первых не перезаписываю данные (это не сложно сделать, но не разумно), а во вторых каждый раз копирую одинаковые данные, что мне не нужно.

В голове понимаю что нужно простенькое сравнение по id например. Но как в итерации сделать это не совсем понимаю.

Спасибо за советы!)

Comment: Надо сделать `id` `AUTOINCREMENT`. Можете поменять сделав такой запрос.

ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `id` `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT; И после этого  в `insert` запросе уже не надо дать `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Шаг 1. Определитесь, исходя из своей задачи, какое поле является первичным ключем у этой таблицы. Заумная теория [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87). По-простому: первичный ключ - это значение, по которому можно точно определить строку, и другой такой в рамках таблицы больше нет и быть не может. Пример: номера квартир в одном подъезде, номера домов на одной улице, номер билета на трамвай в одном тираже. Человека определить однозначно сложнее - имена повторяются, полное ФИО повторяется, но например в рамках РФ для налоговой у нас есть ИНН, у каждого - свой.

Шаг 2. Проверьте, соответствует ли формат вашей таблицы SQL вашему представлению об этой этой таблице. По простому - верно ли она создана, указан ли первичный ключ (PRIMARY KEY), и есть ли у таблицы автоинкрементируемое поле.

Например, ваша таблица может выглядеть примерно так:

```
--
-- Структура таблицы `cont`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cont` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `typeid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `theme` text NOT NULL,
  `times` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Смотреть/править можно в консоли, но мне (и не только) больше нравится [phpMyAdmin](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin). Делать `times` обновляемым при каждом UPDATE не обязательно, это по умолчанию так вбито было ) не стал убирать, вдруг пригодится вам.

Обратите внимание на две вещи:

- `id` AUTO_INCREMENT - это значит, что при INSERT без указания явного значения для `id` он просто будет взят +1 от последнего
- PRIMARY KEY (`id`) - а это значит, что в рамках этой таблицы не может быть двух строк с одинаковыми значениями `id`

Шаг 3. Определитесь, в вашей итерации должна происходить всегда вставка INSERT новой строки в таблицу, или в некоторых случаях нужно делать UPDATE. Если всегда вставка - продолжайте делать только вставку. Если в некоторых случаях нужно обновить данные - делайте последовательно SELECT нужной записи по каким-то критериям, а затем если запись нашлась - делайте UPDATE с WHERE `id` нужной записи, обновляя именно ее, родимую

Comment: Я вас понял. Прочитал и даже усвоил.
Но у меня настолько все криво будет, что при обновлении парсингового(парсуемого?(наглостыренного!)) контента произойдет следующее.
В многих случаях (как и у меня) контент (в моем случае это обновления\новости) появляется сверху. По моему идиотскому алгоритму получится что я не смогу добавить запись так как id =1 уже есть. Или я где то недопонял.

Comment: Если последние записи должны появляется в начале - просто при выборке записей через `SELECT` используйте обратную сортировку `ORDER BY `id` DESC` - по `id` или по `times`. В этом случае в начале у вас будут последние добавленные элементы.